# Conditional colorization of a given cell using VBA, based on multiple criteria from other cells/worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to conditionally color a bunch of cells on Tab1.  I am using data from a column on Tab2 and also a column on Tab3, in an attempt to match to that given cell variables.

Basic logic is:
If there is a match to the cell in column B of Tab2, then check the value in column E of that same row on Tab2.

If that value in column E is greater than zero in Tab2, then colorize the initial cell value in the search range on Tab1 on color... but if I also exist on Tab3 too, then color something else.

Copy and paste of portions of the code.  This is a blown out ‘non-working’ version of the code.  It takes forever to run, if it does run.

```
For Each cellValue In mainRng2

‘if I do not exist in SerializedInvtLocations, but do exist in NonSerializedInventory then check the value in cell E is greater than zero. 
   If VBA.IsError(Application.match(cellValue, Sheets("SerializedInvtLocations").Range("A2:A" & lngLastRowSer), 0)) And Not VBA.IsError(Application.match(cellValue, Sheets("NonSerializedInventory").Range("B2:B" & lngLastRowNon), 0)) Then


    For Each cell In Sheets("NonSerializedInventory").Range("B2:B" & lngLastRowNon)

        x = x + 1
         checker = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cellValue, Range("B" & x), 1, False)

         'if the vlookup value in B2
         If (checker = cellValue) Then
        'i exist in non-serialized list, do I have a quant > 0?

            quant = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cellValue, Range("E" & x), 1, False)

            If quant >= 1 Then
                     cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 8 'teal
                     ‘Sheets("Serialized and Non-Serialized").Range(cell.Address).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                   ‘   Debug.Print "Checker value is: " & checker & " and " & cell.Address & "/" & cell.Value

                   i3 = i3 + 1 ‘ counter

            Else
                       cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'gray

           End If
          End If
    Next cell
   End If

Next cellValue
```

Currently, the file just hangs and does not produce results (or it taking over 40 minutes to run and I just quit out).  If I modify the code and change things up - I CAN get results, but they are not accurate.

EDIT:
Another attempt:

```
If inSer = cellValue.Value And inNon = cellValue.Value Then
    If inNonQuan >= 1 Then
    cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    Else
    cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
End If
If inSer <> cellValue.Value And inNon = cellValue.Value Then
    If inNonQuan >= 1 Then
    cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Else
    cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
 End If
If inSer = cellValue.Value And inNon <> cellValue.Value Then
    cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
If inSer <> cellValue.Value And inNon <> cellValue.Value Then
    cellValue.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
End If
```

Comment: Why are you using VBA rather than just using the built in conditional formatting?

Comment: There is a variable amount of dynamic locations to be colored.  In addition to the colorization, other VBA elements are used to 'drill into' the colorized cells to pull out additional information from them.   So the project was started in VBA and would like to continue down VBA.

Comment: Why do you use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cellValue, Range("B" & x), 1, False)`, you are searching `cellValue` in a Range of size 1?

Comment: How big is sheet, i.e. what is `lngLastRowNon`? In general, I'd suggest using Scripting.Dictionary to read values off the sheet and then do lookup there, rather than using VLOOKUP function.

Comment: The largest of the two column ranges (From Tab2 and Tab3) would be around 90K rows right now, with about 1600 destination cells to color.  I am using WorksheetFunction because it was my 53rd attempt at a resolution for this.  I will look into Dictionary and see where that gets me.

Comment: Where is `cellValue` coming from?

Comment: I have tried to update the code to now show the cellValue.  It was just a range placeholder for the For Each loop counter.

Comment: What is the range on Tab3 that you want to test?

Comment: Looking to match a 'serial number' from "Tab1" cells in the mainRng2 value , to serials in Tab2ColA and Tab3ColB.   Tab2 = ColumnA in "SerializedInvtLocations", Tab3 = Column B and Column E of "NonSerializedInventory".  The ordering of the tabs is not relevant here, I just named them Tab2/Tab3 for simplicity in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something with this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, mainRng2 As Range, t2q As Variant, t3m As Boolean, Tab2, Tab3, wb

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook ?
    Set Tab2 = wb.Worksheets("Tab2")
    Set Tab3 = wb.Worksheets("Tab3")

    Set mainRng2 = wb.Worksheets("Tab1").Range("A2:A1000") 'for example

    For Each c In mainRng2

        'quantity on Tab2 from colE, based on ColB match
        '  will be an error value if no match found
        t2q = Application.VLookup(c.Value, Tab2.Range("B:E"), 4, False)

        'any match on Tab3 ColA ?
        t3m = Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, Tab3.Range("A:A"), 0))

        'did we get a quantity from Tab2 (was there any match)?
        If Not IsError(t2q) Then
            If t2q >= 1 Then
                '15 if also a match on tab3, else 8
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(t3m, 15, 8)
            End If
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim.  I attempted to implement your solution and actually am getting the same 'invalid' results, compared to what I expect to see.  Things are still being miss-colored, and display inaccurately.  I've updated my initial post to include another attempt at breaking down the logic.

Comment: That was my best guess, absent any of your actual data it's difficult to say what the issue might be.  You'd need to debug and identify exactly where it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was disappointingly simple - VLookup only returns the first instance of a matching value, and not all subsequent values.  Instead of vlookup, I should have basically 'summed' the values of a column to get anything greater than zero.